# Count certain values of file in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, file

I have a text file like this (this is a sample, the actual file in very large):

```
[52639 - 2017-12-08 11:56:58,680] INFO __main__.master 251 Finished pre-smap protein tag ('4h02', [], 35000, 665, '67')
[52639 - 2017-12-08 11:57:37,686] INFO __main__.master 251 Finished pre-smap protein tag ('4nqk', [], 35000, 223, '18')
[52639 - 2017-12-08 11:58:46,984] INFO __main__.master 251 Finished pre-smap protein tag ('3j60', [], 3500, 1052, '65')
[52639 - 2017-12-08 12:01:10,073] INFO __main__.master 251 Finished pre-smap protein tag ('4ddg', [], 35000, 541, '38')
[52639 - 2017-12-08 12:03:37,570] INFO __main__.master 251 Finished pre-smap protein tag ('4ksl', [], 35000, 1303, '68')
```

and I want to count the values before the last comma. The result would be 665+223+1052+541+1303 = 3784.

I cannot figure out how to achive this. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, you can try this one:

```
summation = 0

with open("test.txt", "r") as infile:
    for line in infile:
        newLine = line.split(", ")
        summation = summation + int(newLine[3])

print(summation)
```

Output:

```
3784
```

The contents of `test.txt` file are structured like this:

```
[52639 - 2017-12-08 11:56:58,680] INFO main.master 251 Finished pre-smap protein tag ('4h02', [], 35000, 665, '67')
[52639 - 2017-12-08 11:57:37,686] INFO main.master 251 Finished pre-smap protein tag ('4nqk', [], 35000, 223, '18')
[52639 - 2017-12-08 11:58:46,984] INFO main.master 251 Finished pre-smap protein tag ('3j60', [], 3500, 1052, '65')
[52639 - 2017-12-08 12:01:10,073] INFO main.master 251 Finished pre-smap protein tag ('4ddg', [], 35000, 541, '38')
[52639 - 2017-12-08 12:03:37,570] INFO main.master 251 Finished pre-smap protein tag ('4ksl', [], 35000, 1303, '68')
```

If you wish to print all the number that make the sum, you can use a list to store each number:

```
summation = 0
coefficients = []

with open("test.txt", "r") as infile:
    for line in infile:
        newLine = line.split(", ")
        coefficients.append(newLine[3])
        summation = summation + int(newLine[3])

print("+".join(coefficients), end="=")
print(summation)
```

Output:

```
665+223+1052+541+1303=3784
```

Comment: Thank you vasilis. They put in question -4, probably the want to add 2 lines of code like "with open" or something like this. This is the reason that most of us hate stackoverflow. They pretend something that they are not. Anyway thank you.

Comment: Hi vasilis. If my fil is more complicated like this.Suppose that i have in file and lines like this: [52639 - 2017-12-08 11:43:44,850] INFO __main__.master 251 Finished pre-smap protein tag ('4py6', ['R78', 'EDO'], 35000, 33.207404136657715, '16') or [52639 - 2017-12-08 11:43:48,014] INFO __main__.master 251 Finished pre-smap protein tag ('1nw4', ['IMH', 'IPA', 'SO4'], 3500, 153.33520197868347, '64'). Do you have a solution?

Comment: @Antonis well, the community tends to appreciate questions that show research effort and challenge its members into trying to figure out the optimal solution. Besides, Stackoverflow is a wide community ranging from novices to highly skilled members who want to take it one step further. So, questions that show lack of effort or questions that are possible duplicates are unattractive. But, anyway, thanks for accepting my answer.

Comment: Since the number you are interested is always the second from the right, you can write `newLine[-2]`. Be sure to change `int` to `float` to preserve the accuracy.

Comment: Ok, I agree. And I am pretty sure that if I had in my question two lines of code then possibly I would have not any downvotes. The whole phylosophy tend to be wrong and especially from certain users. Anyway, thank you for your answer and for your time.

Comment: Formatting and details play important role when posting a question. Glad to help you though.

Comment: Sure mate. I agree. Anyway, there are different reasons and motivations by using stackoverflow. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
s = """
[52639 - 2017-12-08 11:56:58,680] INFO main.master 251 Finished pre-smap protein tag ('4h02', [], 35000, 665, '67')

[52639 - 2017-12-08 11:57:37,686] INFO main.master 251 Finished pre-smap protein tag ('4nqk', [], 35000, 223, '18')

[52639 - 2017-12-08 11:58:46,984] INFO main.master 251 Finished pre-smap protein tag ('3j60', [], 3500, 1052, '65')

[52639 - 2017-12-08 12:01:10,073] INFO main.master 251 Finished pre-smap protein tag ('4ddg', [], 35000, 541, '38')

[52639 - 2017-12-08 12:03:37,570] INFO main.master 251 Finished pre-smap protein tag ('4ksl', [], 35000, 1303, '68')
"""

pattern = ', ([0-9]*), \'[0-9]*\'\)'

print sum(int(i) for i in re.findall(pattern,s))
```

Have you tried using the regex library? By building a pattern that matches "the numbers before the number that closes with a parenthesis", you can capture all of those number, then build a generator that converts them to integers, and sums them up.